# Unable to locate Dependency (Laravel 5.5) Bootstrap Sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, npm, sass, dependencies

I'm a first time Laravel 5.5 user and I'm looking to incorporate both Bootstrap and Sass into this project I'm working on.  I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to find where this dependency is trying to pull from.

When running a `npm run watch` terminal command it is able to compile it but one it gets to the dependencies it returns the error: `* bootstrap-sass in ./resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` is not found.

Now I locate that file and look and see this:

```
try 
{
  window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

  require('bootstrap-sass');

}
```

Then I search my project for a Bootstrap-Sass file and I'm unable to locate one.  I'm not sure whether a new one needs to be created or I need to pull another dependency in help out.

I'm new to both Sass and Laravel so I feel like I'm diving deep into brand new territory.  I believe once that is resolved and I've understood this correctly; I will be able to plop bootstrap into the app.sass in my assets folder, insert my desired sass commands to style my project, and run web pack to compile everything either through the watch or run dev commands in testing?

Any help will greatly appreciated.  :)

edit //

npm -v shows running 5.4.2

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: yea I ran npm install, it went through the process I saw no errors in the terminal .  Currently node is at 5.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-Resolved:

Hidden in one of the terminal scripts I needed to run this command in the project directory:

`npm install --save bootstrap-sass`

Upon doing this and fixing some of the file paths I was able to correct the error I was getting!